# Mongo error when using aggregation: sort exceeded memory limit

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, memory-limit

I get the mongo error `exceeded memory limit` with error code `16819` when I use aggregation sort.

Im using mongo 2.6.

The query is as follows:

```
db.BASE_TABLE_CREATION_ExecuteHiveScript_26_V0.aggregate([
     { "$project" : { "visitor_localdate" : 1 , "_id" : 0}}, 
     { "$sort" : { "visitor_localdate" : -1}}
])
```

Answer (score 56):

By default aggregation in MongoDB occurs in memory and pipeline stages have limit of 100 Mb RAM. Looks like you have exceeded this threshold. To handle large dataset you should enable aggregation pipeline stages to write data to temporary files. Use [`allowDiskUse`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) option for that:

```
db.BASE_TABLE_CREATION_ExecuteHiveScript_26_V0.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { "visitor_localdate" : 1 , "_id" : 0}},
    { "$sort" : { "visitor_localdate" : -1}}
], { "allowDiskUse" : true })
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, I tried this. It dint worked.. I get the same Exception.

Comment: @acube make sure you really tried this. If you'll look at github sources of mongodb, then you'll find [MongoDB Error Codes](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md) and `16819` code has very clear explanation comment and solution steps:  *Sort exceeded memory limit of bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.*

Comment: when using mongoose use this.
`db.BASE_TABLE.aggregate([]).allowDiskUse(true);`

Comment: See Sonia's answer below. While this will work, if you can move the sort earlier in the pipeline so that MongoDb can utilize an index, the query will not require a memory sort in the first place. This will make it much more performant on large data sets.

Comment: the actual solution is Sonia's answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55491963/4516910

Answer (score 30):

In case you are using aggregate queries.Put an index on the field by which you are sorting and then use sort operator.

**Note:**
Place the sort operator at the beginning of the pipeline or before the $project, $unwind, and $group aggregation operators. If $project, $unwind, or $group occur prior to the $sort operation, $sort cannot use any indexes.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort

Comment: thanks for this, another thing is that for large dataset, do stream and pause resume your stream

Comment: Thanks for the **Note**, I ran into this exact problem of running unwind before sort and kept getting this error. swapping them around fixed it!

Comment: Wow this is a great insight. Thank you

Comment: This is the actual solution. The `allowDiskUse` is just a workaround.

Comment: link fix: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort

Answer (score 22):

Use `{ allowDiskUse: true }` just after aggregation pipeline, like below:

```
db.collectionOrView.aggregate([], { allowDiskUse: true });
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need aggregation for this at all. Use the query

```
db.BASE_TABLE_CREATION_ExecuteHiveScript_26_V0.find({}, { "_id" : 0, "visitor_localdate" : 1 }).sort({ "visitor_localdate" : -1 })
```

and put an index on `visitor_localdate`. This is simpler and faster than aggregation.

Comment: I am getting this error :- "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",

Answer (score 5):

To fix it, enable the allowDiskUse option in your query :

The solution

Reference: Memory Restrictions

In MongoDB, the maximum memory limit for in-sort is 100M, and if you perform a larger sort, you need to use the allowDiskUse option to write the data to a temporary file to sort.

Add the allowDiskUse option to the query:

```
db.bigdata.aggregate(
[
 {$group : {_id : "$range", total : { $sum : 1 }}},
 {$sort : {total : -1}}
],
 {allowDiskUse: true}
);
```

Answer (score 4):

In my scenerio, I fixed it by adding an index for the sorted column

Answer (score 3):

For Mongoose

```
await Model.aggregate([{ $match: { foo: 'bar' } }]).allowDiskUse(true);
```

from https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-allowDiskUse

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for an answer for **pymongo**

and obtain *AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_txn_read_preference'*

**This works:**

```
db.coll.aggregate([], allowDiskUse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me worked a combination of factors:

1. As already have been told I used `{ allowDiskUse: true }` for my typeorm aggregation
2. I had to put `{ $sort: {} }` before the aggregation.

   `[{ $sort: {} }, ...aggregation]`

And finally it worked!

Comment: Sorting definitely did it for me too but I had to sort by something. Thanks!