# Should my aggregate $sort query fail against an indexed collection?

Tags: mongodb

I'm receiving the 100MB memory limit error for sorting against a mongodb collection with indexes.

I found a partial solution to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375017/mongo-error-when-using-aggregation-sort-exceeded-memory-limit) however it does not contain information about indexed collections.

In this [mongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#std-label-agg-memory-restrictions) it states that $sort can only use `allowDiskUse` if "the sort operation is not supported by an index".

My question is, should I be receiving the 100MB limit error if I'm using indexing? Or is it that even with my indexing I'm still reaching the 100MB limit error?

Comment: Please add your aggregation pipeline, and the index details if possible.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor So in my case I would like to answer a theoretical question rather than directly dealing with the code I have. Is it possible to still reach the 100MB limit error even with indexing?

Comment: Depends if your pipeline is using the index, or not. Although it can reach, I doubt that your sorting is using the index.